Element Fails to find during scrolling in mobile using Appium
driver.findElement(
    AppiumBy.androidUIAutomator(
        "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"Hand Sanitizers, Face Masks and PPE Kit Suppliers\"))"
    )
);

Using this, I was able to scroll down on the app but I'm unable to make the scrolling stop on the mentioned accessibility id: Hand Sanitizers, Face Masks and PPE Kit Buyers
and receiving the error:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

I want to scroll down on the application and want to stop the scrolling on the mentioned element then later verify with the assert and tried using the accessibilty id but failing it
